# Touchpad does not register mouse movement

Tags: nvidia, touchpad

My Surface Laptop Studio touchpad worked fine until I installed the nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 22.04.  The touchpad is physically working---I can see this via this tool:

```
sudo libinput debug-gui
```

However, moving my finger on the touchpad no longer moves the cursor.  But pressing-and-moving does indeed move the cursor.

```
$ sudo libinput quirks list /dev/input/event20
AttrPressureRange=25:10
AttrPalmPressureThreshold=500
```

These settings seem to make sense when I run `sudo libinput measure touchpad-pressure`, but maybe I am not understanding what it is supposed to do.  It looks like a light touch shows "up" and a heavy touch shows "down"....

```
$ uname -a
Linux moctar 6.3.2-surface #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri May 12 15:00:39 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /sys/class/dmi/id/modalias 
dmi:bvnMicrosoftCorporation:bvr18.102.143:bd09/13/2022:svnMicrosoftCorporation:pnSurfaceLaptopStudio:pvr124I00060T000M0200000D0B07F1C01P16Y1U00:rvnMicrosoftCorporation:rnSurfaceLaptopStudio:rvr:cvnMicrosoftCorporation:ct9:cvr:skuSurface_Laptop_Studio_1964:
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was from not being on xorg instead of wayland.  After switching to wayland on login, the touchpad seems to work fine.